# Numeros primos em letras a-z A-Z em python

Tags: python

Neste problema você deve ler um conjunto de palavras, onde cada palavra é composta somente por letras no intervalo a-z e A-Z. Cada letra possui um valor específico, a letra a vale 1, a letra b vale 2 e assim por diante, até a letra z, que vale 26. Do mesmo modo, a letra A vale 27, a letra B vale 28 e a letra Z vale 52.

Você deve escrever um programa para determinar se uma palavra é uma palavra prima ou não. Uma palavra é uma palavra prima se a soma de suas letras é um número primo.

Estou em duvida de como fazer o for, eu já criei as variaveis, a = []

```
for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
    a.append(chr(i))
```

Comment: Não entendi qual a dúvida

Comment: Então eu tenho que fazer um for que recebe palavras como numero, so que na hora de eu passa o for para o resultado se é primo ou não, não aceita a string

Answer (score 2):

Basta você definir uma função que retorne o número que represente cada letra:

```
def get_ord_of_char(char):
  if 'a' <= char <= 'z':
    return ord(char) - ord('a') + 1
  else:
    return ord(char) - ord('A') + 27
```

Depois, calcular a soma dos números que representam a palavra:

```
soma = sum(get_ord_of_char(char) for char in palavra)
```

E, por fim, verificar se `soma` é um número primo. Ficaria assim:

```
palavra = 'teste'
soma = sum(get_ord_of_char(char) for char in palavra)
print('A palavra é prima' if is_prime(soma) else 'A palavra não é prima')
```

Basta só você implementar a função `is_prime` que recebe um número inteiro como parâmetro.

Comment: Duvida fico maior ainda agora, e como eu faço a soma verificar se é primo, na hora que eu passo soma como atributo da erro

Comment: @Guilherme `soma` será um número inteiro. Você sabe verificar se é primo? Passar como atributo para onde?

Comment: if soma % get_ord_of_char(palavra) == 0:
  print('é primo')
  soma+=1
else:
  print('não é primo')

Comment: pelo menos o que eu entendi seria isso, o usuario informa a palavra e tenho que verificar se ela é primo ou não de acordo que cada palavra vale um valor, porém, eu não consigo fazer o if nela passando a função que cada numero vale um valor.

Comment: @Guilherme adicionei ao final da resposta um breve exemplo de como ficaria

Comment: eu ainda não consegui entender, pois não consigo fazer o for percorre, já falaram pra eu fazer ate com dicionario mais ta dificil.

Comment: @Guilherme que parte exatamente não entendeu? Eu praticamente coloquei o código pronto ali, não precisa alterar nada, basta implementar a função `is_prime`.

Comment: eu travei na parte de implementar a função, pq quando eu tento implementar a função eu coloquei a outra função como "numero" e acaba sempre dando erro.

Comment: Então edite a pergunta com o seu código, pois está difícil de entender qualquer coisa.

Comment: Essa pergunta é de uma entrevista de estagio, foi dessa maneira que foi pedido, se poder mandar o codigo todo eu agradeço.

Comment: @Guilherme será melhor se editar a pergunta e colocar o que fez. Só assim irei conseguir ver onde está com dificuldade.

Comment: cara agradeço a ajuda mais vou desisti disso ai.